# SSH tunnel won't close after downloading SQL server tables from PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, ssh, pythonanywhere, ssh-tunnel

I'm downloading the tables from my SQL server on PythonAnywhere.com using a ssh tunnel following [their description](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere). Using the following code everything works fine in terms of downloading the tables, but the code then hangs at `tunnel.close()`. Any suggestions on how to stop it from hanging?

```
from __future__ import print_function

from mysql.connector import connect as sql_connect
import sshtunnel
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from copy import deepcopy
import cPickle as pickle
import os
import datetime

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

remote_bind_address = ('{}.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com'.format(SSH_USERNAME), 3306)
tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
                            ssh_username=SSH_USERNAME, ssh_password=SSH_PASSWORD,
                            remote_bind_address=remote_bind_address)
tunnel.start()
connection = sql_connect(user=SSH_USERNAME, password=DATABASE_PASSWORD,
                         host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                         database=DATABASE_NAME)

print("Connection successful!")
cursor = connection.cursor()                      # get the cursor
cursor.execute("USE {}".format(DATABASE_NAME))    # select the database

# fetch all tables
cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
tables = deepcopy(cursor.fetchall()) # return data from last query
for (table_name,) in tables:
    if 'contribute' in table_name:
        print(table_name)

# may hang
connection.close()
tunnel.close()
```

Comment: that's  a puzzler!  shot in the dark: have you tried using the tunnel as a context manager, in a `with` block?  there's an example here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sshtunnel

Comment: I initially used a `with` block, but changed it to this in the hope that it would help.

Comment: the only other thing i can think of is that `deepcopy` - maybe it's leaving a cursor object hanging around so that's why you can't close?  can you try removing it?

Comment: I've tried with the github version rather than the pip version and now it works :)